# Alter TABLE DROP Column - multiple columns MS SQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have several database tables that a lot of redundant columns in that contain no data. Ideally I need to look at dropping these columns.

However since there are hundreds I was looking for a way to use the `DROP COLUMN` command from a table lookup..

So instead of:

```
alter table TableName
    drop column Column1, Column2
```

Something like:

```
alter table TableName
    drop column @ColumnName
```

Using the @ColumnName as a lookup from a table that holds the column names of blank columns, would a cursor work with alter/drop commands?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need dynamic query to drop the columns present in variable

```
exec('alter table TableName drop column '+@ColumnName)
```

Make sure the constraints are dropped before dropping the column